# && Syntax in C for CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on CS50 and haven't gotten a good handle on how to find C syntax guides.

One of the first exercises is to get validate input to be sure that it's between 0 and 23.

I've done that by using two loops, first checking for >0 then checking for <24 but I should be able to do it with one loop using && but haven' been able to figure out how to get it to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    n=-1;
    while (n<0)
    {
        n=24;
        while(n>23)
        {
            n=get_int("Positive Number: ");
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: `if (n >= 0 && n <= 24) { something }`

Comment: oh nice, I was trying (n>=0 && <=24), so that's the issue, needed to repeat the n

Answer (score 2):

Quick primer on the logical `&&` and `||` operators.

For the expression `a && b`:

1. `a` is evaluated and any side effects are applied;
2. If `a` evaluates to 0, then `b` is not evaluated, and the result of `a && b` is 0;
3. If `a` evaluates to a non-zero value, then `b` is evaluated;
4. If `b` evaluates to 0, then the result of `a && b` is 0;
5. If `b` evaluates to non-zero, then `a && b` evaluates to 1.

For the expression `a || b`:

1. `a` is evaluated and any side effects are applied;
2. If `a` evaluates to non-zero, then `b` is not evaluated and the result of `a || b` is 1.
3. If `a` evaluates to 0, then `b` is evaluated;
4. If `b` evaluates to 0, then the result of `a || b` is 0;
5. If `b` evaluates to non-zero, then the result of `a || b` is 1.

By "side effects", I mean expressions like `x++` or `x = y` or something like that.  Given the expression

```
x++ && y
```

The *side effect* of adding 1 to `x` will be complete before `y` is evaluated.  This is how Weather Vane's solution works:

```
while((n = get_int("Positive Number: ")) < 0 || n > 23) ;
```

The logical expression is

```
(n = get_int("Positive Number: ")) < 0 || n > 23
```

First, `n = get_int("Positive Number: ")` executed; the *side effect* is that `n` gets assigned the result of `get_int()`.  That result is compared against `0`; if it's not less than `0`, then `n` is compared against `23`.  Because of how the `||` and `&&` operators work, it's guaranteed that `n` will be assigned the result of `get_int()` before the RHS of the `||` operator is evaluated.

**Edit**

Something I neglected to mention is that both `&&` and `||` force left to right evaluation.  `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so expressions like `a || b && c` are parsed as `a || (b && c)` - however, evaluation always starts with the leftmost expression, which in this case is `a`.

So:

For the expression `a || b && c`:

1. `a` is evaluated and any side effects are applied;
2. If `a` evaluates to non-zero, then `b && c` is not evaluated, and the result of `a || b && c` is 1;
3. If `a` evaluates to 0, then `b && c` is evaluated as described above, and the result of `a || b && c` is the result of `b && c`.

For the expression `a && b || c`:

1. `a && b` is evaluated as described above, and any side effects applied;
2. If the result of `a && b` is 1, then `c` is not evaluated, and the result of `a && b || c` is 1;
3. If the result of `a && b` is 0, then `c` is evaluated, and the result of `a && b || c` is the result of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    while((n = get_int("Positive Number: ")) < 0 || n > 23) ;
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

**Edit:**

Adding some explanation, there is a `while` loop with an empty body shown by the single `;` because the work is done within the `while` condition.

In that condition the first thing executed is

```
n = get_int("Positive Number: ")
```

The result `n` is then tested with `< 0` and another set of parentheses is added to override the usual operator precedence

```
(n = get_int("Positive Number: ")) < 0
```

If `n < 0` the `while` condition is true and the C [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) rule is enforced. It won't matter what the result of the second test `n > 23` is, it will be skipped because the first condition was true.

But if `n >= 0` the second condition `n > 23` is checked.